# Sqlalchemy returns tuple

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

```
class Wishlist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wishlists'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'devices'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    unique_id = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

Every wishlist has `Integer` field with `Device.id`. When i select all wishlists and try to join `Device` object to query:

```
query = db.session.query(
        Wishlist,
        Device
    ).filter(
        ...
    ).join(
        Device,
        Device.id == Wishlist.device_id
    )
```

SqlAlchemy returns for me tuple:

```
(<app.main.models.Wishlist object at 0xa5cec2c>, <app.main.models.Device object at 0xa5d14ac>)
```

But how to set device object like wishlist attribute, to access for it `wishlist.device.id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify both `Wishlist` and `Device` in your call to `query`. If you just want the former with the latter exposed through a property, only specify one.

```
query = db.session.query(
    Wishlist
).filter(
    ...
).join(
    Device,
    Device.id == Wishlist.device_id
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering the examples in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins), something like this should work?

```
for (wishlist, device) in query:
    print wishlist.device_id, device.unique_id # etc...
```